# How to 'git status' to show contents/files of an untracked directory?

Tags: git

I have few new directories in my local repo which contain some auto generated files and some scripts.
 I want to commit and push my scripts to remote repo but skip auto generated files. How do i add these script files from within untracked git directory?
git status -- Doesn't show the contents of untracked files. 
[image: Example]

Comment: if you want to skip auto generated file include them in .gitignore

Comment: Are you asking how to add files, or how to ignore them?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to add some files from test/ and test1/ and ignore others, but i cannot see the contents of these directories in git

Comment: Surely you can see them in `ls`

Comment: Since the directories `test` and `test1` are untracked, Git prevents cluttering the output of `git status` with their content. You can use `ls test` to check the content of the `test` directory.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the git docs, there is an option -u

> git status -u

will show list of all untracked files and I can add them as I want.
plus, I found out that, this can be set into global config file and I can skip -u option with git status

> git config --global status.showUntrackedFiles all

Comment: Also useful is the flag `--ignored` (this will show all files, even if they're in the `.gitignore` file).